# I installed Android Studio on Linux but none of the SDK packages have installed and I can't click on them in the SDK manager

Tags: android-studio, linux-kernel

[All of the packages say 'Not Installed' and I can't click on any of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxuan.png)

I entered `sudo apt update && sudo apt install android-sdk` as another user had suggested and it appeared to download everything but the SDK manager hasn't changed.